# Is it possible to left align centered flexbox elements?

Tags: flexbox, justify

I have created a pen to illustrate what I am working on [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Tupira/mok2jo2c/5/), It has the look and behaviour I want, however I cannot seem to be able to align the flow of contents from left to right as the flexbox as the justify-content is set to center.

Is this possible to do without hacks?

```
#thumbnails {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width:auto;
  justify-content:center;
   background:pink;
   padding-top:30px;


}
```

Comment: What does "from left to right" mean?

Comment: As in, each .thumbnail element flowing next to the other from left to right stacking up to a row without centering if the number of thumbnails is uneven. Does this make sense?

Comment: Ok, so you want some kind of grid where the cells are aligned in columns, right? But Flexbox has no grid notion. Maybe CSS Grids.

Answer (score -1):

If i understood right your problem, remove 
`align-items:flex-start;` and 
set `justify-content:flex-end;` and also add `width:80%;` or play with the percentage as to what you want.

That's really what i understood from your question.

Comment: Thanks but it is still does not work as my two left items are still in the centre.

Comment: Like I said, I "don't" want the items to align in the centre, only their container. If you make the number of thumbnails uneven in your modified pen, the odd item still centers itself.